# vis.js hierarchical network graph layout issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, vis.js, directed-graph

https://plnkr.co/edit/TqnScKGb4pJ0NdZYB5K2?p=preview here is the preview of the graph I have. I am trying to get 'Node 3' on the 2nd level next to 'Node 2'. Shouldn't Vis library know and automatically do that considering 'Node 1' has two edges to Node 2 & 3 and hierarchical layout is enabled with direction UD. I can achieve the desired result by adding level attribute to nodes, but I am looking for an automatic way based on the edges -to & fro info. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
// create an array with nodes
  var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
    {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
    {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
  ]);

  // create an array with edges
  var edges = new vis.DataSet([
    {from: 1, to: 3, arrows: 'to'},
    {from: 1, to: 2, arrows: 'to'},
    {from: 3, to: 2, arrows: 'to'},
    {from: 2, to: 4,arrows: 'to'}
  ]);

  // create a network
  var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
  var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
  };
  var options = {
    interaction: {
        hover:true, 
        tooltipDelay: 300
    }, 
    height: '400px', 
    edges: { smooth: true, shadow: true},
    layout: {
        randomSeed: 1,
        improvedLayout: true,
        hierarchical: {
            enabled: true, //change to true to see the other graph
            direction: 'UD',
            sortMethod: 'directed'
        }
    }
};
```

[image]
And when I change the order of objects in the edges dataset to

```js
var edges = new vis.DataSet([
    {from: 1, to: 2, arrows: 'to'},
    {from: 1, to: 3, arrows: 'to'},
    {from: 3, to: 2, arrows: 'to'},
    {from: 2, to: 4,arrows: 'to'}
  ]);
```

the graph looks like this:
[image]

Is there a way the library figures out the levels and layouts based on the edges dataset. I am trying to create a directed graph.

Comment: I suppose there is no API doing what you need. Did you look at the code of vis.js examples (https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/)?
Anyway I think you can create your own method adding a specific level to a node according to the number of edges linked to that node.